# no sound after realease() the mediaplayer

Tags: android

I made a SoungMagager class in an Android Application Class, so I can use it to manager sound through out the app.  In the SoundManager I have a SoundPool and a MediaPlayer to play some short and longer sounds, respectively.

in order to "clean up" me, I put methods to release() SoundPool and MediaPlayer in the onDestroy() method, and call finish() to exit the app.

My problem is, if I do this finish() and come back the app right away, I have no more sound. no soundpool or mediaplayer.

If I just press the "Home" hardware button to get out, and come back to the app again, there is sound.

If I finish(), then go to system app management and Force Close the app, then run the app again, there is sound.

If I use System.exit(0) in stead of finish(), every thing is fine, but I am told not to do that.

I am suspecting this is because the Application class thing, but I am not sure. How should I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting `soundpool`and `mediaplayer`object in the activity which you are going to finish() so obvioulsy when the activity is being destroyed its instance variable gets released(i mean deleted) so you need to assign the sound to the soundpool of your soundManager class so it will not be destroyed . I think you got my point.

```
public class SoundManager {

    public static SoundPool mSoundPool;
    public static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
      .....
      ....
}
```

now in ur activity in which You are using the soundpool object do this :--

```
   class <your activity> extend Activity{
       @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             SoundManager.mSoundPool = <assign your audio>;
             SoundManager.mMediaPlayer = <assign>;
       }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I can guess what you mean here, but this does not help much.

Comment: so what happen after this changes tell me

Comment: I put SoundManager in Application class so it only needs to load once.